# Android Emulator for Virtualbox

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualbox

I try to do all my development on a virtual machine and I use VirtualBox. Unfortunately, the VS 2017 Android Emulator will not run within the VM. I have two questions.

1. Can anyone recommend an android emulator that WILL run in a VirtualBox VM?
2. Is it possible to run an emulator on a different machine (IP Address) over the internet with port forwarding and all?

TIA

Comment: Hi, Genymotion is an emulator that runs in a VirtualBox VM, have a look at https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/01_Get_Started/Installation.htm

Comment: Thanks @fernandospr, looks interesting. I'd prefer a free solution at the moment but I'll keep this in mind.